# php loop display result if isset and matches the given value

Tags: php

I am sorry to ask such a question but am bit confused about this. 
I am having simple variables defined.

```
$a =1;
$b=2;
$c=3;
$d="";
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    $testa = 1;
    $testb = 4;
    $testc = 3;
    $testd = 7;
    if($a!="" || $b!="" || $c!="" || $d!="") {
       if($a==$testa && $b==$testb && $c==$testc && $d==$testd) {
          echo $testa;
          echo $testb;
          echo $testc;
          echo $testd;
      }
   }
}
```

This is sample php code.
what I need is that I have variables defined at top. SO in my loop i want to display result if user has any 1 variable but in below loop display result based on "and" parameter.
I actually want to skip the empty variable. SO in this case, I want as `$d` is empty, so it should be prevented somehow from `if($a==$testa && $b==$testb && $c==$testc && $d==$testd)` from here.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Just in case :  At the moment, and even if you handle empty values, your `if` will never get through since `$b != $testb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip the empty values from the check, use `||`

```
if ( ... && (empty($d) || $d == $testd)) {
```

Then if you also want to skip it in your echos :

```
echo !empty($d) ? $testd : '';
```